# Can I pass a set of ids for fetching in a restTemplate GET request?

Tags: android, sqlite, resttemplate

I have an android app that connects to SQLite db which returns JSON on requests. One of my classes is called User and at one point my session gets a list of User ids. I'm wondering if there's a way to pass all the ids in one GET call and receive a list of the users back. Something like:

```
    case GET:
                headers.add("Authorization", "Token token=" +token);
                headers.add("params" ListOfIds)
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
                postEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);
                response = restTemplate.exchange(Config.WEB_SERVICE_URL + "favorites",HttpMethod.GET,postEntity, UserList.class);
                break;
```

Comment: what are the results you are getting?

Comment: Do you know how does the service take list of ids? I assume it takes a query parameter? Do you know for sure if it expects headers with bunch of params?